# Only 3 FPS on Mac mini, boot camp, windows 7

Tags: mac, bootcamp

Using the GPU test tool from [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) i get only 3 FPS.

In normal use I notice it when playing fullscreen videos: When the video pans horizontal i get these stripes across the picture.

My setup is like this:

Mac mini 2011 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5/ 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM (PC3-10600)/500 GB HD/Intel HD 3000/Thunderbolt
OS: windows 7
Tv: Panasonic G10 50" plasma
Tv and computer are connected with an 2 meter HDMI cable

I've tried to change the HDMI cable - did not change anything.

What can I try?

Comment: Did you install the bootcamp tools following the Windows 7 install? http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638

Comment: System has been running for 18 moneths without this flickering.
Just upgraded to the latest version of bootcamp software you liked to. But the problem persistes :-(

Comment: Good to hear you've solved it - to represent that on StackExchange, please post your solution as an *answer*, and accept it by checking the adjacent checkmark! Then the question will be formatted as solved in the question list.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, please post the answer below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! - I worked out what the problem was.

I had followed the speedup-tip:

> Head to the Control Panel's Performance Information and Tools section, and choose Adjust  Visual Effects. Here you'll find a long list of effects, but simply choosing "Adjust for  best performance" will turn everything off. You'll feel like you stepped back into a decade ago.

Comment: So, you needed to turn the effects back on again?

Comment: So long ago - cannot remember, sorry